# Yii Database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, yii

I'm designing database for Yii web application and I'm not sure I'm doing it right way.

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE post
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    media TEXT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL,
    create_time INTEGER,
    update_time INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_post_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE comment
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    status INTEGER NOT NULL,
    create_time INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    post_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_comment_post FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
        REFERENCES post (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE tag
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Problems:

1.) In post table I have tag_id. I was thinking to store all existing and newly added tags in tag table and then when someone use already existed tag or made new tag to add as tag_id to post table with ",". Is this the best solution?

2.) In comment table I have user_id and post_id. How I think foreign key are working there should be set 2 foreign keys in comment table? I tried that but got error.

3.) In post table there is media row. I'm going to store in this row location to uploaded image OR embed code from youtube/or any other source. Is this ok to use only same row for that or should I use seperated? 1 for images, 1 for embed code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) In case I'd use column with name `tags` instead `tag_id` where i'd keep serialized array of tag_id's from table `tags`

2) The problem i think because you tried add foreign keys with same name. 
Try to use

```
CONSTRAINT FK_comment_post FOREIGN KEY
CONSTRAINT FK_comment_post_2 FOREIGN KEY
```

3) What will be if you'll decide to add another media info in post(pdf_file, or music). Add new column in table post it's not correct. i'd recommend you create additional table `postmeta` where you can create any type of content, and instead `media` use `post_text`. Like  in wordpress.